# how to draw only falling half of spline in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, spline

I am able to draw a spline in three.js by specifying three coordinates, namely - start, mid and end. On doing so, the curve starts from the coordinates of 'start', rises all the way up to mid and falls down to the coordinates of 'end'. This is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jopahelimi/edit?html,css,js,output) for the same.

However, I would like to now draw only the falling half of the spline, that is, the part from 'mid' to 'end' alone.

This is the traditional spline.
[image]

However, I would like to get only the falling half, as below, but would like to fit the scene.
[image]

EDIT : Adding the code below

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r75/three.js"></script>

<script>
    // global variables
    var renderer;
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var geometry;

    var control;

    var count = 0;
    var animationTracker;

    init();
    drawSpline();

    function init()
    {
        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render, sets the background color and the size
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 40;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    function drawSpline(numPoints)
    {
        var numPoints = 100;
//        var start = new THREE.Vector3(-5, 0, 20);
        var start = new THREE.Vector3(-5, 0, 20);
        var middle = new THREE.Vector3(0, 35, 0);
        var end = new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, -20);

        var curveQuad = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(start, middle, end);

        var tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curveQuad, numPoints, 0.5, 20, false);
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
            opacity: 0.9,
            transparent: true
        }));

        scene.add(mesh);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I mentioned about wanting only the falling portion to 'fit the scene'. What I meant was that just the falling portion should occupy as much space as the entire image is occupying now. Otherwise, if were to trim out only the vertices after 'mid' from the spline, then the part of the spline would be very small, just like in the second image below (which is cropped out using paint).

Comment: In my hands, your jsBin does not produce any output. Also, your jsBin defines 3 functions: init, drawLine and drawSpline, but drawLine is never called/invoked.

Comment: @AndrewWillems, so sorry that you weren't able to see the output. I checked once again, and I am able to see it. Have posted the code above. Yes, drawLine() is not needed, you may ignore that.

Comment: Just so you know...after your comment/response, I checked, and your jsBin does NOT work in Firefox (v45.0.1) but DOES work in Chrome (v49.0.2623.87).

Comment: @AndrewWillems, thanks Andrew. Is there a way I can get the second half of the spline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show below one way to draw half (or any proportion) of a 3d quadratic bezier curve. The math is based on DeCasteljau's algorithm (if I understand correctly). The math is shown in the extra functions I have included in the code, i.e. `splitQuadraticBezierCurve` and `getPointAtT`. THREE.js has some functions that do something similar to `getPointAtT`, specifically `getPoint`, and there is also a `getTangent` function. However, I don't quite yet know how to use `getTangent`, so I ended up just implementing the math myself. It's not that difficult anyway.

The basic principle behind splitting the curve can be understood better with the following diagram:

[image]

The `v` stands for vector (or point), and `v0`, `v1` and `v2` are retrieved from your initial quadratic curve and are your original `start`, `middle` and `end` points. `v01` and `v12` are a distance `t` (in your case, 0.5) along the indicated lines, and `v012` is a distance `t` between `v01` and `v12`. The function returns a 2-element array with the first (element 0) and second (element 1) 'halves' of the original quadratic curve. The start, middle and end points of the first 'half' curve are `v0`, `v01` & `v012`. The start, middle and end points for the second 'half' curve are `v012`, `v12` & `v2`.

The code produces the following image for the second 'half' curve:

[image]

This image is manually cropped. Getting the shape to "fill" the screen was done manually. To do this "filling" programmatically depends on what you're interested in changing and/or willing and/or able to change: the camera's position? the camera's angle? the camera's field-of-view? the object's position? the view width/height/proportions? Thus, I haven't addressed that here. However, I hope this answer shows you at least how to split a quadratic bezier curve.

```
// global variables
var renderer;
var scene;
var camera;
var geometry;

var control;

var count = 0;
var animationTracker;

init();
drawSpline();

function init()
{
    // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    // create a render, sets the background color and the size
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
    camera.position.set(0, 40, 40);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 15, 0));

    // add the output of the renderer to the html element
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function getPointAtT(vA, vB, t) {
    return new THREE.Vector3(
        vA.x + (vB.x - vA.x) * t,
        vA.y + (vB.y - vA.y) * t,
        vA.z + (vB.z - vA.z) * t
    );
}

function splitQuadraticBezierCurve(quad, t) {
    var v0   = quad.v0;
    var v1   = quad.v1;
    var v2   = quad.v2;
    var v01  = getPointAtT(v0,  v1,  t);
    var v12  = getPointAtT(v1,  v2,  t);
    var v012 = getPointAtT(v01, v12, t);
    var firstHalf  = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(v0,   v01, v012);
    var secondHalf = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(v012, v12, v2  );
    return [firstHalf, secondHalf];
}

function drawSpline()
{
    var numPoints = 100;
    var start = new THREE.Vector3(-5, 0, 20);
    var middle = new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 0);
    var end = new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, -20);

    var curveQuad = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(start, middle, end);
    var FIRST_HALF = 0;
    var SECOND_HALF = 1;
    var curveProportion = 0.5;
    var secondHalfCurveQuad = splitQuadraticBezierCurve(curveQuad, curveProportion)[SECOND_HALF];
    var tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(secondHalfCurveQuad, numPoints, 0.5, 20, false);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
        opacity: 0.9,
        transparent: true
    }));

    scene.add(mesh);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Andrew. This was very useful and nifty.